# How to optimize short string lexing in Python for speed

Tags: python, optimization, cpython

I'm trying to **lex** (i.e., tokenize) *escaped* strings in pure CPython *fast* (without resorting to C code).

The best I have been able to come up with is the following:

```
def bench(s, c, i, n):
    m = 0
    iteration = 0
    while iteration < n:
        # How do I optimize this part?
        # Inputs: string s, index i
        k = i
        while True:
            j = s.index(c, k, n)
            sub = s[k:j]
            if '\\' not in sub: break
            k += sub.index('\\') + 2
        # Outputs: substring s[i:j], index j

        m += j - i
        iteration += 1
    return m

def test():
    from time import clock
    start = clock()
    s = 'sd;fa;sldkfjas;kdfj;askjdf;askjd;fasdjkfa, "abcdefg", asdfasdfas;dfasdl;fjas;dfjk'
    m = bench(s, '"', s.index('"') + 1, 3000000)
    print "%.0f chars/usec" % (m / (clock() - start)  / 1000000,)

test()
```

However, it's still somewhat slow for my taste. It seems that the invocation of `.index` is taking a lot of time in my actual project, though it doesn't seem to happen quite as often in this benchmark.

Most strings that it needs to lex can be assumed to be relatively short (say, 7 characters) and are unlikely to contain backslashes. I've already optimized for that somewhat. My question is:
**Are there any optimizations I could make to speed up this code? If so, what?**

Comment: What are the tokens here?

Comment: Also, are you allowing yourself to use regexes?

Comment: @user2357112: Whatever is inside the quotes, as a single string. In the example the token would be `abcdefg`.

Comment: @user2357112: Would they actually be faster?

Comment: Probably. This looks like a job for a regex to me. What should happen if there's a backslash before a quote that would otherwise start a quoted string?

Comment: @user2357112: Backslashes just cause the next character to be skipped like they always do; there's no correctness issue here. As for regexes, if you can actually show they would be faster, I would love to see it, because it seems to me that the overhead here is in the function calls... and regexes would require more function calls, right?

Comment: There's a lot of overhead here in just bytecode evaluation. Depending on whether you need the indices, a regex solution could just take one call to `findall`.

Comment: @user2357112: Huh, that's a great point about the indices... let me try that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks, your advice worked! My code got around ~20% faster. Interesting to note, though, is that if I run it with PyPy, it's actually slower to use regexes!